# Pandas How To Turn Header into Series so I can make a Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've got 155 headers in my dataframe I need to change to make them easier to read/call. So I'm creating a dictionary which I'll use to replace the headers.

I think I need to do these 3 things

1. Create a series of the headers
2. Create a txt file with the series of headers
3. Append : and the new name to the new header series

I might be making a mountain out a mole hill, and should maybe just do this in excel but I'm trying to get better at python and thought this would be good practice.

This is what I've did so far

```
recols = research[0:0].squeeze()
recols = recols.transpose()
recols.to_csv("list.csv", index=False)
```

When I call

```
recols
```

I get this output (I added the ... so to not put every header name)

```
    <bound method DataFrame.transpose of Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Gender, Region, Age, Social Grade,...]
Index: []

[0 rows x 155 columns]>
```

I'm sure I'm missing a crucial step but I can't find what it is.

Here is the output when I print:

> Empty DataFrame Columns: [] Index: [Gender, Region, Age, Social Grade,
>   Operating system on smartphone used most frequently, 1. Choice (Have
>   you ever written a review and/or rating of a product such as a meal,
>   holiday, celebrity, home appliance etc, online?), 2. I wanted to
>   publicly acknowledge how good/bad the product or service that I
>   received was (What are usually your main reasons for leaving reviews
>   or ratings?), 2. I wanted to feel better in myself by leaving feedback
>   where other people may see it (What are usually your main reasons for
>   leaving reviews or ratings?), 2. I wanted to help other people make an
>   informed decision on a product or service (What are usually your main
>   reasons for leaving reviews or ratings?), 2. I wanted to help the
>   person/organisation who provided the product or service to improve
>   their offering (What are usually your main reasons for leaving reviews
>   or ratings?), 2. Other (What are usually your main reasons for leaving
>   reviews or ratings?), 2. Other Data (What are usually your main
>   reasons for leaving reviews or ratings?), 3. Mobile - Apple device
>   (What devices do you usually use when leaving a review or rating?), 3.
>   Mobile - Android device (What devices do you usually use when leaving
>   a review or rating?), 3. Tablet  (What devices do you usually use when
>   leaving a review or rating?), 3. Computer (What devices do you usually
>   use when leaving a review or rating?), 3. Other (What devices do you
>   usually use when leaving a review or rating?), 3. Other Data (What
>   devices do you usually use when leaving a review or rating?), 4.
>   Choice (Have you ever read a review or rating online, and used it to
>   help you when making a purchase?), 5. Choice (On average, how often do
>   you tend to leave reviews or ratings online? Please select best
>   match), 6. Choice (How many times in the last six months have you left
>   a review or rating for a product or service online?), 7. Choice (What
>   generally triggers you to write a review or rating online the most?)

Comment: Change `recols = recols.transpose` to `recols = recols.T`

Answer (score 1):

transpose is function call you need () and end of it.

```
recols = research[0:0].squeeze()
recols = recols.transpose()
recols.to_csv("list.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: That's got it into a series thanks. My text file still isn't generating. Is my code malformed?

Comment: Am I right in saying that it should store it to the same location as the script in the way I've coded? If that is true then I'm definitely looking in the right place.

Comment: You can do a `import os` and `os.getcwd()` to confirm that your working directory is where you expect it to be. Your file will be saved in your working directory.

Comment: @CliffChew did that. It's the right directory I'm looking at. Really odd, read the documentation and it doesn't say to do anything else.

Comment: When I print I get a list. I should get a dataframe, right?

Comment: @NickDuddy it should be dataframe. could you please post some data you have?

Comment: @NickDuddy, hmm... without the data, I am assuming that you can't use the `to_csv()` method on a list, which is causing the weird situation. It's weird that no error popped up though, although I have never tried to use that method on a list myself. You can try `pd.DataFrame(recols).to_csv("list.csv", index=False)`, just to see your output is works? Just to be sure we are on the same page here, I import my pandas using `import pandas as pd`.

Comment: @CliffChew I've posted a sample of the output above.

Comment: @NickDuddy Sorry for my late reply. It says that your dataframe is actually empty. I think that might be the reason why the output doesn't occur.

Comment: @CliffChew Oh! is that [] immediately after columns? In that case do you know why it has an index?

Comment: @NickDuddy Hmm... I would debug it line by line. Seems like some part of your code is causing the dataframe to be empty. You try just executing `research[0:0].squeeze()` to see what you get?